# Node.js - Xml Parsing

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-parsing, body-parser, xml2js

I have used many xml parsers till now, but non of them helps me to achieve my objective. A list of parsers that I've used is `xml-body-parser`, `xml2js`, `libxmljs` and `xamel`.

I want to do following things

- Parse XML and insert all elements one by one to an array (obviously using a loop)
- Update attributes of a specific element, no matter whatever it's depth is
- Preserve the sequence of xml nodes as they were before parsing
- response the updated xml

Till now, I've just accomplished to send xml and then response xml, nothing else

**Code till now is**

```
var express = require("express"), 
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

require("body-parser-xml")(bodyParser);
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var builder = new xml2js.Builder;
var app = express();
var util = require('util');

app.use(bodyParser.xml({

    xmlParseOptions: {
        normalize: false,    
        normalizeTags: false, 
        explicitArray: false
    }
}));


var XmlPosted;
app.post('/users', function (req, res, body) {
    XmlPosted = req.body;
    console.log();
    res.send(builder.buildObject(req.body));
    res.status(200).end();
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me, things done in this code are

1. Specific xml tags are searched and then new attributes are being set
2. XML was parsed
3. Updated response is sent

   ```
   var DOMParser = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser({ normalizeTags: { default: false } });
   var express = require("express"),
       bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   require("body-parser-xml")(bodyParser);
   var xml2js = require('xml2js');
   var builder = new xml2js.Builder({ standalone: { default: false } });
   var app = express();
   //Options of body-parser-xml module

   app.use(bodyParser.xml({
       xmlParseOptions: {
           normalize: false,     // Trim whitespace inside text nodes
           normalizeTags: false, // Transform tags to lowercase
           explicitArray: false // Only put nodes in array if >1
       }
   }));

   //Post Method
   app.post('/users', function (req, res, body) {

       //Parsing Request.Body
       var document = DOMParser.parseFromString(
           builder.buildObject(req.body).toString()
       );
       //Getting a list of elements whose name is being given
       var node = document.getElementsByTagName("TextView");

       //Changing Tag Name of Specific Elements
       for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
           node[i].tagName = "com.mycompany.projectname.TextView";
       }
       //Responsing Updated Data
       res.send(document.toString());
   });
   app.listen(1000);
   ```